# How is the Quaternion multiplication derived?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, quaternions

Quaternion multiplication seems suspiciously similar to the cross product. How is it derived?

Here is a  description of the multiplication:
Let $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ be two quaternions, which are defined, respectively, as $(w_1, x_1, y_1, z_1)$ and $(w_2, x_2, y_2, z_2)$.

$(Q_1  Q_2).w = (w_1w_2 - x_1x_2 - y_1y_2 - z_1z_2)$

$(Q_1  Q_2).x = (w_1x_2 + x_1w_2 + y_1z_2 - z_1y_2)$

$(Q_1  Q_2).y = (w_1y_2 - x_1z_2 + y_1w_2 + z_1x_2)$

$(Q_1  Q_2).z = (w_1z_2 + x_1y_2 - y_1x_2 + z_1w_2)$

Comment: It comes from the basic formula $i^2=j^2=k^2=ijk=-1$, where $1=(1,0,0,0)$, $i=(0,1,0,0)$, and so on. For example, $ijk=-1$ implies that $ijk^2=-k$ so $ij=k$. You can derive similar rules for the multiplication of any pair of basis elements, and then by distributivity extend it to all quaternions. // By the way, the cross product is indeed hidden in there: If you write $(w,x,y,z)$ as $w+\vec v$ where $\vec v=(x,y,z)$, then $(w_1+\vec v_1)(w_2+\vec v_2)=w_1w_2-\vec v_1\cdot\vec v_2+r_1\vec v_2+r_2\vec v_1+\vec v_1\times\vec v_2$.

Comment: what do you mean "derived"? Quaternions are essentially defined by the formulas you list, which can be recast as Rahul Narain notes in his comment. However, exactly why the quaternions are what they are is more a historical question. To derive them you first need some characterization independent these formulas. Then you can search and find the given multiplication. For example, Hamilton. There are many other number systems which extend $\mathbb{C}$ and are not the quaternions...